# Dependency Property does not get or set Value

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have created a user control in WPF, and in the code behind I have created some dependency properties.

I added several WPF controls to my user control, one of the is a progress bar, so What I tried to do is to expose the Value progressBar property as below:

```
     public static readonly DependencyProperty valueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(Double),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            ValuePropertyCallback));

    private static void ValuePropertyCallback(DependencyObject controlInstance, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MyUserControl myUserControlInstance = (ProgressControl)controlInstance;
        myUserControlInstance.progressBar.Value = (Double)args.NewValue;
    }

    public Double Value
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(valueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(valueProperty, value); }
    }
```

And in XAML I have written this:

```
<MyUserControl Name="myControl" Value="{Binding ProgressBarValue}" >
```

But It seems not to be working, neither setting nor getting the value.

I have a couple hours reviewing this but I cant realize what I am doing wrong.

Hope you can help me, Thank you in advance.

(**Note:** DataContext are defined previously and it is correct since this is the only binding that does not work)

Comment: [Binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)? Did you overwrite the DataContext locally and now it won't inherit another data context as you expected?

Comment: with the debugger can you see if you enter the callback ?

Comment: @H.B. I have already verified that, actually I have more properties which work, for that reason this problem is too weird to me, since all my other properties work fine

Comment: @VincentPiel, Yes I have done that, and I never enter to the callback, but I know that it works because if in design time I put an arbitrary value to my property, the Progress bar changes its "progress" aspect

Comment: try changing to smthg like : new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyCallBack( ValuePropertyCallback))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that my problem was that I didnt implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, so, the changes I did were not showed. But since I am new at WPF using MVVM I didnt know that.

But you just need to create an ObservableObject, then your viewModel class has to inherit from it.

[Here](http://justinmchase.com/2010/08/26/observableobject-for-wpf-mvvm/) is an example to create the ObservableObject class and how to inherit from it.

Answer (score 1):

valueProperty  <---->  "Value"  does not match...  (v/V) :=)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but According what I have read, "valueProperty" is my dependency property which registers my "Value" property, isnt it?

Comment: @Dante: You are right, it does not matter what the field is called.

Comment: sure H.B., it does not matter... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx  look at "Dependency Property Name Conventions" to see that "The naming convention of the property and its backing DependencyProperty field is important."

Comment: @VincentPiel: I tried it, it does not matter what the field is called.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Mode=TwoWay:

```
<MyUserControl Name="myControl" Value="{Binding ProgressBarValue, Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

I have also used `PropertyMetadata` instead of `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didnt know that, and I think it is useful, but It is still not working. This is really weird since I had created some dependencies before and they worked :(

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the name of your dependency property to be PascalCased:

```
ValueProperty
```

You might also want to look at [BindsTwoWayByDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions.aspx) to make sure changes to your DP are written to the source object.